# Display DataGridView values in text boxes based on matching values - vb.net

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, textbox

I have an SQL query that returns 2 columns of values:

```
country  |  number
NA       |    1
IN       |    2
CN       |    3
DE       |    4
```

And so on.

I am trying to do one of the following:

1. Assign these values to variables I can copy to an excel workbook
2. Or just use the DGV as a medium to copy values to text boxes.

For example, I have a form with country labels and textboxes next to them. I would want to click a button and have the data copied to the matching text box.

DGV number value where DGV row value = CN would be 3 and that value would be copied to the CN value text box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only using the DGV as a medium, but not actually displaying it, use a dictionary instead. Output the SQLDataReader using the SQLcommand(cmd) with the country code being the key and the number being the value. Then its as simple as:

```
Dim dc As Dictionary(Of String, String) = New Dictionary(Of String, String)
Dim cmd As SqlCommand = "your query string"
cmd.Connection.ConnectionString = "your con string"
Using sqlrdr As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
     While (sqlrdr.Read())
          dc.Add(sqlrdr(0), sqlrdr(1))
     End While
End Using
```

Then just output to the textbox:

```
txtNA.Text = dc.Item("NA")
```

Comment: Thank you for this Ethilium! i am fairly new to all this and was not aware of the dictionary. This actually worked perfectly for what i needed!!!

Answer (score 0):

If the countries are fixed as your question refers, then you could use something like this:

First, use the names of the countries to name the TextBoxes (txtNA, txtIN, txtCN,...)

Then you can put this code:

```
    Try
        For i = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
            Me.Controls("txt" & DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(0).Value.ToString).Text = _
            DataGridView1.Rows(i).Cells(1).Value.ToString()
        Next
    Catch
    End Try
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this - it wasn't QUITE what i was looking for but will actually help with something else i was working on =)

Comment: @RyanOtto Np.. also if you explain more about what you're looking for, maybe I will be able to help you :)

Comment: i apologize!! after re-reading your code and comment - what you said actually works PERFECT! all 3 were useful. Yours actually works best for me because it leaves blank text boxes with no value.

Comment: I'm glad I've helped. If you have any other concerns, let me know. If not, please click on the answer as 'accepted'. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

*The following will not work 'as is' if using classes via dragging tables from the data source window in the ide. We would need to cast objects not to a DataTable but to the class definition in a TableAdapter, DataSet and BindingSource.*

Here is a method which reads from SQL-Server database table, places data into a DataTable, data table become the data source for a BindingSource which becomes the data source for the DataGridView. Using a BindingSource we now use the BindingSource to access row data rather than the DataGridView and it's always best to go to the data source rather than the user interface.

BindingSource.Current is a DataRowView, drill down to Row property then field language extension method to get strongly typed data for the current row if there is a current row as you will note I am using two forms of assertions, first, do we have a data source and is the data source populated then we see if there is indeed a current row.

From here we can set variable, properties or control text to the field values of the current row.

Note in form load I seek a specific country (totally optional) and then if found go to that row.

Least but not last, I like using xml literals when doing SQL in code so there is no string concatenation and we can format the statement nicely.

```
Public Class Form1
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Permits obtaining row data in DataGridView
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Dim bsCountries As New BindingSource

    Public Property Country As String
    Public Property CountryNumber As Integer

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim dt As New DataTable

        Using cn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection With
            {
                .ConnectionString = My.Settings.KarenDevConnectionString
            }
            Using cmd As New SqlClient.SqlCommand With {.Connection = cn}

                ' xml literal to make command text
                cmd.CommandText =
                    <SQL>
                    SELECT [ID],[Country],[Number]
                    FROM [Countries]
                    </SQL>.Value

                cn.Open()

                dt.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader)

                dt.Columns("ID").ColumnMapping = MappingType.Hidden

                bsCountries.DataSource = dt
                DataGridView1.DataSource = bsCountries

                ' let's try and move to a country
                Dim index As Integer = bsCountries.Find("Country", "CN")
                If index > -1 Then
                    bsCountries.Position = index
                End If
            End Using
        End Using
    End Sub
    ''' <summary>
    ''' Put field values into TextBoxes
    ''' </summary>
    ''' <remarks></remarks>
    Private Sub DoWork()
        If bsCountries.DataSource IsNot Nothing Then
            If bsCountries.Current IsNot Nothing Then
                Dim row As DataRow = CType(bsCountries.Current, DataRowView).Row
                TextBox1.Text = row.Field(Of String)("Country")
                TextBox2.Text = row.Field(Of Integer)("Number").ToString

                ' we can also do this
                Me.Country = row.Field(Of String)("Country")
                Me.CountryNumber = row.Field(Of Integer)("Number")
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        DoWork()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Thank you for this Karen! from reading over the code it is a bit over my head! =) however i will still play around with it and better learn what is going on!